# Where to sit a door in a doorway through concrete wall?

Tags: doors, construction, door-frame

Trying to think of the best place to sit a door in this renovation.

As you can see its a concrete wall with a lintel and airbricks as well. I will be building an internal CLS timberframe studwall (100mm x 50mm)

[image]

Do I put the door on the timber frame or sit the door inside the opening?

As you can see from this diagram I drew: with options 1 or 2

[image]

I suspect there is no "right" answer

Comment: what direction is the door going to swing?  #2 will only allow the door to open 90 degrees, where #1 with an outward swinging door will allow the door to open more.

Comment: The door will open into the room (is that outward?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the door is "in the wall" it's going to partially block the opening, as it can only swing to 90 degrees, more or less.

If the door is in the timberframe, it can swing more fully out of the way against the wall, 180 degrees, more or less.

If the opening is quite wide, this may not matter. If not, it can make a large practical difference, particularly when moving furniture.

Comment: Maybe less than 90 degrees if the doorknob, etc. gets in the way.

Comment: Which part of "more or less" did you fail to comprehend? In the case as drawn, the knob should be in the room and not be a factor for angle, though the knob from the exposed face of the door projecting into the opening is yet another obstacle to moving furniture in that case.

Comment: None. I'm agreeing with you. What part of  _"less than 90 degrees if the doorknob, etc. gets in the way"_ is tripping you up?

Comment: Nobody ever seems to think of the movers when they design stuff. Plus eleventy for mentioning that!

Answer (score 1):

Put the door so that it's surface is flush with the finished wall of the large room.

That will look best.